# List all added or modified files in ALL branches since a base Git commit

Tags: git

I worte some code a while ago that is probably comitted in a branch.
I have about 100 brances and don't remember which, or the file name.

Is there a way to get a list of all added and modified files in all commits of all branches since some specific base commit(tag|hash|branch). Then hopefully I will recognise the filename and then know the branch.

Output something like:

```
hash     branch  file
----     ------  ----
C0DE1234 branchA file1.txt
C0DE1234 branchA file2.txt
C0DE2222 branchA file3.txt
C0DE3333 branchB file4.txt
C0DE4444 branchC file5.txt
C0DE4444 branchC file6.txt
```

Comment: Changes to files don't happen in branches, but commits store snapshots. To search code in all commits, use `git log -S'searchterm' --all`